# How to drag and drop files to a places applet. (Like trash can)

Tags: gnome-panel, applet, drag-and-drop

I made a shortcut to my home folder by dragging and dropping it to the panel.

Is there a way that I can drag and drop files to that applet in order to save the file
in the folder location?

What I really want is to make a shortcut to one of my Ubuntu One folders, that when I drag and drop a file, selected text or url to that applet, it saved the dropped 'element' in the folder for synchronization purposes.

## EDIT

Like the trash can but with a custom selected folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script will act according to your desciption. I believe this is not the best approach for this situation, but there is not an applet with the functionality described by you that I know of.

Create a file in your home folder with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

ubuntuone_loc="/home/user/Ubuntu One/"

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ;
then 
  nautilus "$ubuntuone_loc"
else
  (
    i=0
    for file in "$@" ; 
    do
      echo $(($i * 100 / $#))
      i=$(($i+1))
      cp "$file" "$ubuntuone_loc"
    done
    echo 100
  )|zenity --progress --title="Copy files progress" --text="Copying $# files to $ubuntuone_loc..." --auto-close &

  RUNNING=0
  while [ $RUNNING -eq 0 ]
  do
    if [ -z "$(pidof zenity)" ]
    then
      kill $(pidof cp)
      RUNNING=1
    fi
  done

fi
```

**Make sure you replace "/home/user/Ubuntu One" with your ubuntu one folder**. Now create a new custom launcher, and fill in "sh /path/to/the/created/file". The new launcher should work with clicking and drag and drop.

I hope this works for you. A custom Ubuntu One applet with this sort of behaviour would be nice.

Comment: I did this and indeed it's working. The only problem is that it works only for files, no for dropping of links nor selected text. I modified your code for testing and when dropping a selected text or link $# equals 0. I guess one have to do a 'proper' applet using C or python. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I must say I think that is a great idea. The problem is that I don't think an applet is the best approach. I personally feel like applets don't fit well in to the desktop. If you want to continue with this idea make sure you let me know.